# How to pass Model route name item to linkTo in template in ember.js

Tags: ember.js, handlebars.js, ember-router

How do I pass a route name to a {{linkTo}} dynamically?

For example, given this code:

```
App.Router.map(function() {
 this.resource('anon', {path: '/main'},
 function() {
   this.route('home', {path:'/home'});
   this.route('about', { path: '/about' });
   this.route('contact', { path: '/contact' });
 });
});

App.NavController = Ember.ArrayController.extend({
  selectedNav:'',
  setNav:function(value){
  var nav = App.Nav.find(value);
  var items = nav.get('navItems');
  this.set('content', items);    
  }
});
```

these templates:

```
<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="nav">
  <ul class="nav">
    {{#each in controller}}
      {{ partial "basicNav"}}
    {{/each}}
   </ul>
</script>

<script type="text/x-handlebars" data-template-name="_basicNav">
  <li>{{#linkTo navItemPath}}{{navItemName}}{{/linkTo}}</li>
</script>
```

and these models with the following fixture data:

```
App.Nav = DS.Model.extend({
  navItems:DS.hasMany('App.NavItem'),
  name:DS.attr('string')
});

App.NavItem = DS.Model.extend({
  nav:DS.belongsTo('App.Nav'),
  navItemName:DS.attr('string'),
  navItemPath:DS.attr('string')
});

App.Nav.FIXTURES = [
 {
  id: 10,
  name: 'Anon',
  navItems: [100,200,300]
 }
];

App.NavItem.FIXTURES = [
{
  id:100,
  nav:10,
  navItemName:'Home',
  navItemPath:'anon.home'
},
{
  id:200,
  nav:10,
  navItemName:'Contact',
  navItemPath:'anon.contact'
},
{
  id:300,
  nav:10,
  navItemName:'About',
  navItemPath:'anon.about'
}
];
```

How do I pass navItemPath to the {{linkTo}} helper? In this code snippet:

```
{{#linkTo navItemPath}}{{navItemName}}{{/linkTo}}
```

ember complains that it can't find the "navItemPath" route, like it's looking for it literally. If I replace that with a valid literal route like:

```
{{#linkTo 'anon.home'}}{{navItemName}}{{/linkTo}}
```

ember will render the linkTo with the navItemName as expected, so I know the controller is passing it the right data, but of course all the routes are goofy. Am I missing something obvious?

Comment: Add router.map into question. You need to use router resource name in quotes and after that pass an argument. Something like this `{{#linkTo "nameOfResource" objectWhichContainsRouteId}}{{navItemName}}{{/linkTo}}`

Comment: Thanks, @Giedrius. I updated the question to include my router. I can see the data being passed in correctly. If I, for example, change navItemName to navItemPath, I see the route string being passed in. Do you know if {{linkTo}} MUST be passed a string? Again, I am trying to pass a ref to a string from my model and its acting like its trying to read the ref literally. Thanks for the feedback!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't do that with LinkTo helper, you need to bind the *href* of your link to `navItemPath` using [bindAttr](http://emberjs.com/api/classes/Ember.Handlebars.helpers.html#method_bindAttr)

```
<a {{bindAttr href="navItemPath"}}>{{navItemName}}</a>
```

Make sure the the logic rending navItemPath's value takes into account the [location](http://emberjs.com/guides/routing/specifying-the-location-api/) API

Comment: Thanks, @ken, I did end up going that direction.