# Ember.js pass route from controller to linkTo

Tags: ember.js

In my controller I have the following definition:

```
 this.tabs = Ember.A([
                Ember.Object.create({
                    title:"All Contacts",
                    active:true,
                    linkTo:"contact.list.all"
                }),
                Ember.Object.create({
                    title:"My Contacts",
                    active:false,
                    linkTo:"contact.list.my"
                })

]);
```

and in my html I have the following loop:

```
{{#each tab in tabs}}
        <li {{bindAttr class="tab.active:active"}} > {{#linkTo tab.linkTo data-toggle="tab"}} {{tab.title}} {{/linkTo}}</li>
{{/each}}
```

When I run this view I get an error saying "The route tab.linkTo was not found", because the linkTo Helper exepects a route object.

I've also tried passing route directly using e.g.

```
linkTo:App.Router.router.getHandler("contact.list.my")
```

but I get the same error.

So how can I dynamically set the route for linkTo helper?

Comment: This is duplicate of [this SO question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14666103/how-to-pass-model-route-name-item-to-linkto-in-template-in-ember-js)

Comment: thanks! didn't find that post

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16021148/emberjs-how-to-dynamically-generate-link-with-linkto